# Cannot understand how is a function looped without loop function in python while finding factorial number

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

```
def factorial(num):
    if num == 0:
        return 1
    return num * factorial(num-1)

print('Enter an integer')
num = int(input())
print(factorial(num)
```

If I input number `4`, output is `24`.

Inside the above code block, I cannot understand line 4.

Though there isn't any loop, how does that function multiply all the numbers
under a given number and returns the value that we expected?

Comment: Welcome to the beautiful world of [recursion](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute it in your head. For example - what is `factorial(2)`? 2 is not 0, so it is `2 * factorial(1)`. Now what is `factorial(1)`? 1 is still not 0, so it is `1 * factorial(0)`. What is `factorial(0)`? Now 0 is 0, so we know it's 1. Going backwards now to plug in our missing pieces: if `factorial(0)` is 1, then `factorial(1)` is `1 * 1`, then `factorial(2)` is `2 * 1 * 1`.

With [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), there is a base (or terminating) case which is known, and all the other cases are reduction to simpler problems that approach the base case. You know `factorial(24)` only if you know `factorial(23)`, you know `factorial(23)` only by knowing `factorial(22)`... but you know `factorial(0)` unconditionally. If there is no terminating case, then you get the equivalent of an infinite loop - an infinite recursion.

In order to understand recursion, you should first understand recursion.